# Windows 10 Pro to Home USB stick conversion

Tags: windows, usb, windows-10

I have created a Windows 10 Pro USB stick with the `Windows Media Creation Tool` (https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10). The tool asked me if I would like to install Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Pro, I chose Pro. Now I am wondering if there is a simple way to convert the installation from Pro to Home (by changing a configuration file on the USB stick or something similar). The reason I am asking is I don't want to download all the files again and I think the Home version should be integrated in Pro version.

Comment: The tool asked so it knew which version to provide, and that's what you downloaded. You need to start over with the tool and answer it differently.

Comment: The question was: is there a way no to start all over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible with Windows 10.

There was a trick to switch between Windows Vista ISO editions like this (I think it also worked for Windows 7), but since Windows 8 only one variant is available per downloaded file (with exception of Windows 10 x86+x64 downloads, because x86 and x64 versions are treated as separate editions and ISO contains both of them).

You can try to open `install.wim` or `install.esd` file from the ISO (7-Zip will extract `.wim`, `.esd` can be converted to `.wim` and I'm not aware of any programs that will open it directly). There should be one XML file and some folders. Each folder is one edition, if there's only one (called `0`) then no other editions are available in that ISO.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. They're 2 completely different installations.